# How do you use ljust inside a fstring?

Tags: python, string, formatting

Requirements

- I have some float values and strings I want to print out in one line
- I have multiple lines to print
- I want it formatted like a table without lines

Problem

- The `-` signs of the float values degrades the look (the values won't be in line)
- I can `f"{myfloat:+}"` to give all the values signs. But, then I can't use `str.ljust` method
- I tried `f"{str(myfloat:+).ljust(10)}"` which of course threw an error

```
# My current code
values = [-1.0, 2.2]

for value in values:
    formatted = str(value).ljust(10)
    print(f"someLjustedStrings{formatted}someLjustedStrings")

#Output
#someLjustedStrings-1.0      someLjustedStrings
#someLjustedStrings2.2       someLjustedStrings

#Expected Output (best)
#someLjustedStrings-1.0      someLjustedStrings
#someLjustedStrings+2.2      someLjustedStrings
#OR
#someLjustedStrings-1.0      someLjustedStrings
#someLjustedStrings 2.2      someLjustedStrings
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
values = [-1.0, 2.2]

for value in values:
    print(f"someLjustedStrings{['+', '-'][value<0]}{abs(value):<10}someLjustedStrings")
```

Output:

```
someLjustedStrings-1.0       someLjustedStrings
someLjustedStrings+2.2       someLjustedStrings
```

`<` followed by `int` for `ljust`

`>` followed by `int` for `rjust`

**EDIT:**

If you want to `ljust` by variable:

```
LJUST = {'value': 10}
values = [-1.0, 2.2]

for value in values:
    print(f"someLjustedStrings{['+', '-'][value<0]}{abs(value):<{LJUST['value']}}someLjustedStrings")
```

Output:

```
someLjustedStrings-1.0       someLjustedStrings
someLjustedStrings+2.2       someLjustedStrings
```

Comment: I've never seen such code before. If you can clarify me please. `[value<0]` evaluates to an index `0` or `1` from boolean value. Which prints the sign. And `:<10` acts as a `ljust`?

Comment: Is there a way to specify the amount of `ljust` from variables? Ex) `f"{value:<LJUST["value"]}"`

Comment: @InyoungKim Put another pair of braces around the variable. Check the edit.